# what would the cardinality be in the given set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Given $\{m \in \{0,1\}^b |  m[2,3,4] = 100\}$ assuming that $b \geq 5$ and $b \in 
\mathbb{N}$

I'm thinking the cardinality of this set would be $2^b/3$ in terms of $b$ since there are $2$ choices $0$ or $1$ $b$ number of times but $m[2,3,4] = 100$, but I feel I'm wrong..

Comment: What is $m[3,4,5]$?

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini I think the notation $m[2,3,4]=100$ means $m_2=1\land m_3=0\land m_4=0$.

Comment: Oops it was suppose to be $m[2,3,4]$, but it means that that portion of the string must be  $100$. For example say we have a string $0010011$ notice the $2,3,4$ bits are $100$.

Comment: @Mario Carneiro Yes correct

Answer (score 0):

The cardinality is $2^{b-3}$, because there are $b-3$ binary choices to be made for any function in the set (there would be $b$ choices, but three of them are already made for you).  More rigorously, there is a bijection from your set $S$ to $\{0,1\}^{b-3}$ setting $f(m)=\langle m_0,m_1,m_5,\dots,m_{b-1}\rangle$; since none of the indexes $0,1,5,\dots,b-1$ are restricted in $S$ this is surjective, and it is injective because if $m_0=n_0,m_1=n_1,m_5=n_5,\dots,m_{b-1}=n_{b-1}$, then we also have $m_2=1=n_2$, $m_3=0=n_3$, $m_4=0=n_4$, so $m_i=n_i$ for each $i$ and hence $m=n$.

Answer (score 0):

Since three of the bits are fixed there is no choice in choosing them,
for the other b-3 bits we have no restrictions.
Therefore, number of ways to do this is $2^{b-3}$